# Ensuring subscribing multiple times produces expected behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, observable

I am working on the front end of a recipe recommendation API. Given a userID, I can subscribe to a getRec() function and retrieve a list of recommendations (recipeid, ingredientid) for which I am to:

- subscribe to a getRecipe() function and convert recipeid to recipe information

```
 recipes: IRecipe[] = [];

 public recommend() {
    this.recipes = [];
    var ingredientids: number[][] = [];

    this.listService.getRec(this.cookie.get("userid")).subscribe((rec) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < rec.length; i++) {
        this.listService.getRecipe(rec[i].recipe).subscribe((recipe) => {
          this.recipes.push(recipe);
          this.addRecommendedItems(i, rec[i].ingredients);
          console.log(this.recipes);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

- for every ingredientid in the recommendation, subscribe to a getRecommendedItems() - which converts the ingredientid to a shopitemid
- for every resultant shopitemid, subscribe to a getItem() - which converts shopitemid to shop item information

```
  private addRecommendedItems(recipe_index, recipe_ingredientsids) {
    this.recipes[recipe_index].items = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < recipe_ingredientsids.length; j++) {
      this.recipes[recipe_index].items[j] = [];

      this.listService
        .getRecommendedItems(recipe_ingredientsids[j])
        .subscribe((cart_items_ids) => {
          for (let k = 0; k < cart_items_ids.length; k++) {
            this.listService
              .getItem(cart_items_ids[k])
              .subscribe((cart_item) => {
                this.recipes[recipe_index].items[j].push(cart_item);
              });
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

The problem is that subscribing in a row like follows produces unexpected results and shop items of a recommended recipe are not always populated. How can I transform this code to ensure this does not happen?

Used interfaces are as follows:

IRecipe:

```
export interface IRecipe {
  id?: number;
  title?: string;
  instructions?: string;
  items?: IFoodItem[][];
}
```

IFoodItem:

```
export interface IFoodItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line `this.recipes.push(recipe);` to `this.recipes[i] = recipe;` in the `recommend` function.

Comment: Huh?! I can't believe that was it. Would you mind elaborating the difference between `this.recipes.push(recipe);` and `this.recipes[i] = recipe;`? Thank you very much.

Comment: Should I also do a similar change for `this.recipes[recipe_index].items[j].push(cart_item);`?

Comment: The `getRecipe` callback doesn't return in the same order you invoked it. So for example if you got back three recommendations and you invoke `getRecipe` for each, the second recipe might return before the first one. In this case in your original code the second recipe will be the first one in the `this.recipes` array.

Comment: The `this.recipes[recipe_index].items[j].push(cart_item)` only needs to be changed if the order of the cart items matter to you.